# How to POST via $.ajax() to ASP.NET WEB API?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I keep getting a null parameter once the WEB API method is hit.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var product = {
name: "productA",
Id: 22
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:50175/api/values/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: product
})
.success(function(data) {
    alert('success');
})
```

WEB API

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]Product value)
{
    setResponse();
}
```

Product class

```
public class Product
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you are not doing anything wrong, its working perfect for me.

Comment: I am using query-1.11.3.min.js. I faced similar issue in past, what I suggest to rename   var product to  var value, so that parameter name of web API method and what you are passing from AJAX are of same name.

Comment: I'm using jquery 2.1.4.

Comment: Try changing `url` to `api/values/Post`! I just got working here! It just works fine with the normal too!

Comment: Adding /POST produces 404 as expected.

Comment: Have your tried specifying the contentType?  Also, as a side note, why not remove the [FromBody] Product and replace with HttpRequestMessage?

Comment: Removing [FromBody] at least provides a non null object.  But its properties are null.  [HttpRequestMessage] isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  var product = {
name: "productA",
Id: 22
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:50175/api/values/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(product),
    dataType: "json"
})
.success(function(data) {
    alert('success');
});
```

Comment: Can you provide what JSON.stringify(product) statement is giving to you ?

Comment: {"name":"productA","Id":"22"}

Answer (score 1):

You need to append `Post` to the url:

```
var product = {
    name: "productA",
    Id: 22
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:50175/api/values/Post',
    type: 'POST',
    data: product
})
.success(function (data) {
    alert('success');
})
```

**Screen shot**

[image: Break point hit]

Comment: That isn't how Web API works.  Besides, if I do that, nothing happens.

Comment: @4thSpace Honestly that is all I changed to get it working as you can see in the screenshot. You could add a `RouteAttribute` if you prefer your URL. The only difference in my posted answer was the port url, which I have changed to match yours. You might have an issue outside of the code you have posted. I would try it in a new solution just to maybe isolate the problem. Do you get any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant to post JSON to your WebAPI.

You must specify the encoding and encode it yourself.  By default jQuery will form url encode the data parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:50175/api/values/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(product),
    contentType: "application/json"
})
.success(function(data) {
    alert('success');
});
```

Comment: Still null parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 function YourMethodName() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '~/api/values/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    product : {
                        name: $('#IdOfInputName"').val(),
                        ID: $('#idofInputID').val()
                    },
                }),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (result) {
                   // your code 
                },
                error: function (result) {
                   //your code 
                }
            });
        };
```

Comment: Tried that.  Object is valid but properties still come through as null.

Answer (score 0):

Cobbling together pieces of everyone's answers, I found the solution.

Remove `[FromBody]` in the Web API parameter.  @Big Daddy mentioned this in an OP comment but then said to use `HttpRequestMessage`, which is not available.

Using code from the OP, the above is the only modification.

Some additional comments, at least for my scenario:

- Don't use `JSON.stringify()`, which I was not in the OP.
- `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` will cause values to be null
- `type` didn't matter
- Don't append `Post` to the endpoint URL

I'm not sure why [FromBody] is there in the first place.  I guess Microsoft is assuming everyone will be POSTing FORMs?  That's unrealistic.